# Displaying an image in php using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display an image along with other information from the database.

**PHP**

```
  <?php
               mysql_connect("localhost","111","222") or die("Could not connect to localhost");
               mysql_select_db("movies") or die( "Could not connect to database");

               $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM allmovies");
               if ($result == false )  die(mysql_error()); 
               while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
               {
                    echo "<img src=' . $row['image'] . '>";
               ?>
```

Like:

> Title: Blah
>   Price: Blah
>   Image: `<img src=rarara">`

All from MySQL in one page?

Comment: I hope you've got a good reason for using the ancient `mysql_query` interface.

Comment: what you are storing in db? its path or what?

Comment: I'm storing the .png file under as a blob

Comment: How are you storing the byte string? base64 encoded?

Comment: [BLOB 44.4 KiB] that's what it says

Comment: before echo you have to use Header commant to show browser that this is an image instead text

Comment: Well, if it's a png, then you shouldn't send jpeg headers.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't store image data in a database, they are generally not suited to this and incurs extra overhead on your MySQL connections returning the data. You should be storing *the path to the image file*, and serving that.
2. If you insist on doing it you you should only be returning *one* image at a time with the *proper* header based on the image type using something like the following:

   ```
   $imagedata = data_from_mysql();
   header('Content-Length: ' . sizeof($imagedata) );
   header('Content-Type: image/png');
   echo $imagedata;
   exit;
   ```
3. If you *really* want to make your page source bloated, slow, unmanageable, and nigh-uncacheable:

   ```
   while( $imagedata = data_from_mysql() ) {
     echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($imagedata) . "'>";
   }
   ```

I cannot stress enough how these are ***terrible ideas*** that you ***should not use***, but if you cannot listen to reason you can at least do bad things the right way.

Comment: @ Sammitch okay, thanks. I changed it to the path now. I'm trying to use echo "<img src=' . $row['image'] . '>";

Comment: You're mixing single and double quotes there, `echo '<img src="' . $row['image'] . '" />';` or better yet `printf('<img src="%s" />', $row['image']);`

Comment: Are you saying you just changed the structure of your site and are now storing paths instead of image blobs? If so, consider relative or absolute paths. <img src="/uploads/images/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>"> where $row['image'] = something like 'entry-1.jpg' as opposed to storing a full path in your database. It makes more sense to store filename, then make the path a system variable in case you move things around

Comment: @KaiQing I'd recommend against absolute paths since that ties your code to the particular machine it's on at the time and makes changing hosts/machines/providers/OSes/etc a major pain.

Comment: @Sammitch - I mean writing absolute in the src attr of the tag instead of echoing $row['image'] as is. Assuming the db result is just a file name or something

Answer (score 1):

You could use [imagecreatefromstring()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($row['image']);
if ($im !== false) {
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($im);
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' .  base64_encode($data)  . '" />';
}
```

Just my opinion, but it might be slightly more sane to save the images to the file server and then store a reference to the path instead of the whole image as a blob?